# Coffeescript HTTP client

Tags: node.js, http, coffeescript

I am running `server.coffee` from this page: https://github.com/xenph/foaas

From the command line, you can do:

```
curl http://localhost:5000/off/Name1/Name2
!@#$ off, Name1. - Name2
```

But I'm using the code from this page: http://coffeescriptcookbook.com/chapters/networking/basic-http-client

```
http = require 'http'

http.get { host: 'http://localhost:5000/off/Name1/Name2' }, (res) ->
    data = ''
    res.on 'data', (chunk) ->
        data += chunk.toString()
    res.on 'end', () ->
        console.log data
```

The error I get is:

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
  at errnoException (dns.js:37:11)
  at Object.onanswer [as oncomplete] (dns.js:124:16)
```

Which leads me to believe that it's not finding the url.

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
http.get 'http://localhost:5000/off/Name1/Name2', (res) ->
```

or

```
http.get { hostname: 'localhost', port: 5000, path: '/off/Name1/Name2' }, (res) ->
```

instead of

```
http.get { host: 'http://localhost:5000/off/Name1/Name2' }, (res) ->
```

maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly extract a little more info from exceptions:

```
.on('error',function(e){
   console.log("Error: " + hostNames[i] + "\n" + e.message); 
   console.log( e.stack );
});
```

Secondly as curl is working we can assume that the service is up and accessible from localhost so there must be a deeper issue. What flavour of linux are you using? I've solved similar issues before by disabling firewall (iptables) and selinux.

Also double check to make sure that you have dns configured and that it will return 127.0.0.1 for localhost. Use nslookup.